# Thread.sleep() causes ANR in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-anr-dialog, android-thread

This code runs on a background Thread:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        a = a+1;

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("","", t);
        }           
    }
}
```

In developer console I see ANR report:

> ANR Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because
>   the touched window has not finished processing certain input events
>   that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.)

```
"myThread" prio=5 tid=7 SUSPENDED
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x11111111 self=0x22222222
  | sysTid=11111 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=333333333
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=3 core=1
  at java.lang.VMThread.sleep (Native Method)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep (Thread.java:1013)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep (Thread.java:995)
  at com.example.MyThread.run (MyThread.java:123)
```

How can I fix this ANR?

Comment: post complete code though why you want your thread keep on sleeping

Comment: no, it's on working thread, and can't cause ARN. Your error comes from another block of code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are making an incremental command inside a `while(true)` loop.